# How can make the requests_futures module not create an error with Heroku?

Tags: heroku, requests-futures

When I try deploying my Flask app to Heroku, I get a ModuleNotFound Error for requests_futures.

I have included it in requirements.txt and I am still getting the issue. Heroku deploys fine without the requests_futures module. Is there anything I can do?

```
2022-11-07T22:26:40.279231+00:00 app[web.1]: from app.main import app
2022-11-07T22:26:40.279231+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
2022-11-07T22:26:40.279231+00:00 app[web.1]: from .tools.web_scraping import web_scrape
2022-11-07T22:26:40.279231+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app/tools/web_scraping/web_scrape.py", line 4, in <module>
2022-11-07T22:26:40.279232+00:00 app[web.1]: from requests_futures import sessions
2022-11-07T22:26:40.279232+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_futures'
2022-11-07T22:26:40.279381+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-11-07 22:26:40 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-11-07T22:27:10.906569+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-11-07 22:27:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-11-07T22:27:10.906610+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-11-07 22:27:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-11-07T22:27:11.054365+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2022-11-07T22:27:11.153534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-11-07T22:27:11.963376+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shows-4-u.herokuapp.com request_id=e0cd543f-98cc-486f-a27e-8f07b97c720f fwd="148.101.185.226" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-11-07T22:57:34.354131+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shows-4-u.herokuapp.com request_id=937c2b54-5df2-4e42-b056-1582c6137e0c fwd="148.101.185.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my requirements.txt

```
appdirs==1.4.4
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2022.9.24
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
click==8.1.3
cssselect==1.2.0
fake-useragent==0.1.14
Flask==2.2.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==5.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
lxml==4.9.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
parse==1.19.0
pyee==8.2.2
pyppeteer==1.0.2
pyquery==1.4.3
requests==2.28.1
requests-futures==1.0.0
requests-html==0.10.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
tqdm==4.64.1
urllib3==1.26.12
w3lib==2.0.1
websockets==10.4
Werkzeug==2.2.2
zipp==3.10.0
```

This is the build log

````
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
 !     
 !     A Python security update is available! Upgrade as soon as possible to: python-3.10.8
 !     See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
 !     
-----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
-----> Installing python-3.10.7
-----> Installing pip 22.3.1, setuptools 63.4.3 and wheel 0.37.1
-----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2020.11.15
       Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (3a221c)...
       Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
         Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 115.8/115.8 kB 443.5 kB/s eta 0:00:00
       Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
       WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (/tmp/build_1fedda59/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages)
       Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.9.3
       Ignoring importlib-metadata: markers 'python_version < "3.10"' don't match your environment
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 48.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v21
       https://shows-4-u.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
Starting November 28th, 2022, free Heroku Dynos, free Heroku Postgres, and free Heroku Data for Redis® will no longer be available.
If you have apps using any of these resources, you must upgrade to paid plans by this date to ensure your apps continue to run and to retain your data. For students, we will announce a new program by the end of September. Learn more at https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter```
````

Comment: Do you also have a `Pipfile`?

Comment: I don't have a Pipfile, but I do have a Procfile, which just says <web: gunicorn wsgi:app>

Comment: The `Procfile` is unrelated. Are you entirely sure that you committed your `requirements.txt` file and deployed from the correct branch? Did you see dependencies get installed when you deployed? Did it say "with pip"?

Comment: I installed all of the dependencies within the ```venv```.  I only have one branch to deploy from, and I did not see any dependencies get installed when I deployed. I just connected my GitHub to deploy.

Comment: Your local virtual environment is irrelevant. Heroku installs dependencies itself as part of its deployment process. I don't use the GitHub integration feature; can you access the deploy logs somehow? Maybe in the dashboard? That's where you should see dependencies getting installed.

Comment: This is what the build log says

Comment: The build log is too long so I added it to the question

Comment: Right, so the log says you have a `Pipfile.lock` (which means you almost certainly _do_ have a `Pipfile`). In that case, Heroku uses Pipenv, not pip, to install dependencies. Your `requirements.txt` file will be completely ignored in favour of your `Pipfile.lock`: `Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2020.11.15`, `Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock`. See the duplicate questions.